# How to override a base implementation

Tags: oop, go

Say I have the following Go struct:

```
type PubSub struct {
    bus.Publisher
    bus.Subscriber

    context context.Context
}
```

bus.Publisher exposes this method:

```
func (p *Publisher) CreateTopic(context context.Context, topicName string) *pubsub.Topic
```

PubSub struct has its own `CreateTopic` method in an attempt to override `CreateTopic` in Publisher to provide additional behavior as follows:

```
func (p *PubSub) CreateTopic(context context.Context, topicName string) *pubsub.Topic{

    if !strings.HasPrefix(topicName, "mem://"){
        topicName = "mem://" + topicName
    }

   // how do I make this method override the implementation provided by bus.Publisher?
}
```

How do I achieve this in Go?

Comment: Seems to me like all you need is to invoke the publisher's CreateTopic passing it the modified input, which you can do with `return p.Publisher.CreateTopic(context, topicName)`... but maybe I misunderstood the question? And as far as "overriding" the behaviour of a concrete method on a concrete type, that's not doable in Go. If that's what you think you need you'll need to redesign.

Comment: You just define it, as it appears you already have. Are you experiencing an actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

You seems to already override it.

You may want to call the parent method

```golang
func (p *PubSub) CreateTopic(context context.Context, topicName string) *pubsub.Topic {
    if !strings.HasPrefix(topicName, "mem://") {
        topicName = "mem://" + topicName
    }

    return p.Publisher.CreateTopic(context, topicName)
}
```